# Installing applications with different user accounts on linux

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, access-rights

I have basic question about installing applications on `linux` operating system. i am going to express my issue considering oracle db installation as a example. when installing oracle database , i created a user group called `dba` and and user in this group called `ora112`. so this users is allowed to install database. so my question is if `ora112` uses `umaks` is set to `077`, then no other uses will be able to configure oracle database. why do we need to follow this practice. is it a accepted procedure in application installation on `Linux`. please share your experience with me. thanks in advance for looking into this issue

say i install `Java` application in this way. then no other application which belongs to different user account won't be able use `Java` running on this computer because of this access restriction.

what is the default permission used when installing an application. is it `770`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mistaking permissions with `umask`s. If you install the database with, say 770 permissions, anyone in the `dba` group will be able to do what they need in there.

On a different topic, if the user `ora112` has a umask set to 077, then when he creates a new file, he'll create it by default with the permissions 700. This means you'll have to manually chmod everything ora112 creates in order to let other group members of `dba` modify it.

Again, note how the umask is different from the permissions of the actual installation!

Comment: say i install java with 700 permission. then no other applications installed using different user account will not be able to make use of java installation.

Comment: if i am correct , what is the default permission used when installing an application

Comment: Usually, you'll want some sort of root users to have rwx permissions, while group and other have only r-x. Unless there's confidentiality at hand, in which case only group will have r-x and other will have ---